# AutoCompleteTextView with search ime options

Tags: android, search, kotlin, autocompletetextview, ime

I want to do the searching 2 ways with autocompletetextview. The first one is the basic one which uses ArrayAdapter (This one works fine), the second one is using IME_OPTION_SEARCH or actionSearch. I want to discuss the second one which is the problem here.

Basically, I need to add imeOptions to autocompletetextview with "actionSearch" and it would be like this:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/acPetShopSearch"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivPetShopSearchIcon" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/pet_shop_search_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/pinkish_grey" android:textColor="@color/purple_brown"
            android:textSize="12sp" android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Then, I set editor listener to the view like simple EditText with actionSearch, so it would be like this:

```
acPetShopSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(object : TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
        override fun onEditorAction(v: TextView, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                doSearch(acPetShopSearch.text.toString())
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    })
```

I tried this and I got the error like this:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter event
>           at id.paw.pawcolony.view.petshop.PetShopActivity$successCity$1.onEditorAction(Unknown Source:7)
>           at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:6271)
>           at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:138)
>           at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:360)
>           at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:85)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)

Is the AutoCompleteTextView's behavior is different from EditText? Is there any way to put search feature to AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: I want to do search in 2 ways. First, the search can be done by click the item on AutoCompleteTextView. And second, I want to do search just from what I type, not from adapter. Is it possible? @pskink

Comment: @pskink but this is Android apps, not using jquery, so maybe we discuss different things

Answer (score 1):

```
acPetShopSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(object : TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
        override fun onEditorAction(v: TextView, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                doSearch(acPetShopSearch.text.toString())
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    })
```

Fixed mine by making KeyEvent nullable